# Does statting /proc/PID/stat make the kernel generate the contents so that a file size is returned?

Tags: linux, proc

I'm implementing an alternative to `top`, and thought that I should preallocate an appropriately sized buffer to hold the read contents of `/proc/PID/stat`.

However, knowing that it's a pseudo filesystem where contents of files will be generated on-demand, will simply statting that file result in the kernel doing work to generate its contents, so that a file size is returned?

Answer (score 1):

From `stat(2)`:

> For most files under the `/proc` directory, `stat()` does not return the file size in the `st_size` field; instead the field is returned with the value `0`.

So, no, it does not, and so it seems to be impossible to exactly allocate the buffer size needed. But given the small and predictable nature of these files, a couple KiB seems to be more than enough.